# NFA from regular grammars

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, finite-automata

I am trying to make an NFA from this regular grammar

$$\{a^n \mid n > 0\}\cup \{b^m a^k \mid m\ge 0,k \ge 0\}\;.$$

This is what I have now.

The last part, $a\ge 0$, is the one I am not sure of.

[image]

Comment: The state $1$ seems redundant. And think about what happens if you feed $abaa$ (which it should accept) to your NFA. Finally, why is state $2$ colored blue? If that means that it's an acceptance state, you need to rethinkt this - your NFA is also supposed to accept $a$ and $aba$, neither of which makes it end up in state $2$.

Comment: @fgp From previous posts by the same user, green seems to be the accept states. It would be nice if the OP would specify this in their post, however!

Comment: In this case, I suggest to the OP to consider the input $ab$, which his NFA should also accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, it misses in both directions: for instance, it doesn’t accept $baa$, which is in the language, and it does accept $aba$, which is not. The first thing that you need to do is remove the $a$ loop at state $0$. Then state $0$ accepts the empty word, which is in $\{b^ma^k:m,k\ge 0\}$, and state $1$ takes care of all of the words $a^n$ with $n>0$. Moreover, you’ll no longer be able to accept anything that starts with $a$ and then has at least one $b$. In fact, the resulting automaton almost works: in addition to $a^n$ for $n>0$ and the empty word, it accepts $b^ma$ for each $m\ge 0$, and it doesn’t accept anything that’s not in the language.

It still misses some words that *are* in the language, however: it misses every $b^ma^k$ with $m\ge 1$ and $k\ge 2$, and it misses every $b^m$ with $m\ge 1$. Making state $2$ an acceptor state takes care of the $b^m$ words; how can you take care of the $b^ma^k$ words with $m\ge 1$ and $k\ge 2$?